# Device Driver Make file error

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I have written the following make file ( basically to compile a device driver ) and i am not able to compile my code.

Here is my Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

        KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

    # The current directory is passed to sub-makes as argument
        PWD := $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

abc: abc.c
    gcc abc.c -o abc -lpthread

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions abc

.PHONY: modules modules_install clean

else
    # called from kernel build system: just declare what our modules are
    obj-m := xyz.o
endif
```

I get the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-53-generic/build M=/home/some/something LDDINC=/home/some/something/../include modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/some/something/xyz.c', needed by `/home/some/something/xyz.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/some/something] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

It would be great if anybody could point out what are the errors that i might be doing

Comment: How will you create the target `xyz.o` from `xyz.c`. That's the rule you will have to make:

Comment: Have you examined whether this file `/home/some/something/xyz.c` exists?

Comment: Yes the file xyz.c exists in the directory /home/some/something i am not able to figure out the mistake